# Editing files with shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, awk

I'm developing a script, and it perform calculations that need to include in a text file already filled.
The format of the file lines is:

```
1 20/10/16 12:00 take car in the garage joe's garage
```

Inside the script I get a number from calculations, and that number will replace the first number of the row. For example, the "calculate" returns the value 15, then the script must access the file in question and change the row in question should look like this:

```
15 20/10/16 12:00 take car in the garage joe's garage
```

The point is that I do not know how to accomplish this change. It can be in bash, awk, sed, or any available resource. Thank you.

Comment: how this 15 is calculated ? 15 is calculated based on the 1st line number values ?

Comment: Yes. I use the difference between the date line and the current date. And the value is contained in a variable.

Comment: tell me, how you calculated 15 from this line ?

20/10/16 12:00 take car in the garage joe's garage

Comment: This date is in format DD/MM/YY. I verify the ramining days to the date of line and i increase the first number of line (works like a priority level) according to proximity.

Comment: The number that i need to edit is ever in the first column. I need to replace this number with a value stored in a variable.

Comment: how 15 is calculated from 20/10/16. if the second line has 21/10/16.. then you expect to place 16 in the front of second line ?

Comment: It depends on which is the first line number. This number works as a priority task to the line. The new priority is calculated based on the current priority and the remaining days to complete the task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46776/discussion-between-d-alves-and-kamaraj).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
awk -v old=$oldNum -v new=$newNum \
'{if ($1==old) {$1=new; print} else {print}}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Tried it like this:

```
$ cat input.txt
2 19/10/16 15:30 some other line
1 20/10/16 12:00 take car in the garage joe's garage
3 17/10/16 5:30 another one

$ oldNum=2
$ newNum=15
```

Run the awk command, then:

```
$ cat output.txt
15 19/10/16 15:30 some other line
1 20/10/16 12:00 take car in the garage joe's garage
3 17/10/16 5:30 another one
```

Is this what you wanted ? If you want your result to appear in the original file, just `mv` the output file with new name `input.txt`, that should overwrite the input file (use an anti-slash `\mv` to avoid aliasing of the `mv` command).

NOTE: you can probably obtain the same result with shorter awk instructions, but this syntax makes it more readable. `sed` can probably do it in an even more concise way.

---

EDIT: I realise this works if you want to change only 1 number within your file. If I understand your problem correctly, you want to re-calculate the number for *every* line and create a file with those new numbers. The optimal way of doing that would be to include your calculation of new line number *inside* the `awk` script, that way you don't have to create a shell loop, which is generally a bad idea since calling tools like `awk`, `echo`, `sed`... repeatedly ends up being very costly. You could do something like this:

```
if [ -f $PWD/output.txt ]; then 
    # Remove old output if present in current directory
    \rm -f $PWD/output.txt
fi

awk '{ ###calculation here, result store in newNum###; $1=newNum; print}' input.txt > output.txt
```

For example, if I want to trivially just increment by one every line number:

```
awk '{$1++; print}' input.txt > output.txt
```

If you cannot (or dare not) include your calculation inside `awk`, you can do a loop on the file, but that's pretty clumsy from what I understand of `bash` scripting:

```
if [ -f $PWD/output.txt ]; then 
    # Remove old output if present in current directory
    \rm -f $PWD/output.txt
fi

while read line
do
    newNum=###Calculation here for current line###
    echo $line | awk -v new=$newNum '$1=new' >> output.txt
done <input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
awk -v num="$variable" '{$1=num}1' input.txt
```

Comment: I try, but this replace all line's first numbers.

Comment: how i replace only the line in question?

Comment: how i replace only the actual line?*

Comment: is it always first line ?

Comment: No, the archive contains n lines, and i need to replace one by one.

Comment: why dont you provide a simple input and expected output and logic

Comment: @Kamaraj I think this was made clear in the original question that OP wants to only change one specific line. Please fix this answer, because you're really close

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short python script that does what you want. Usage is simple: give it file, number that line starts with, and the number you wish to see instead

Demo:

```
    bash-4.3$ cat data.txt 
    2 19/10/16 15:30 some other line
    1 20/10/16 12:00 take car in the garage joe's garage
    3 17/10/16 5:30 another one
    bash-4.3$ python renumber.py data.txt 1 15
    ['renumber.py', 'data.txt', '1', '15']
    bash-4.3$ cat data.txt 
    2 19/10/16 15:30 some other line
    15 20/10/16 12:00 take car in the garage joe's garage
    3 17/10/16 5:30 another one
```

Code:

```py
import sys
import os

print(sys.argv)

with open(sys.argv[1]) as inputfile:
    with open('/tmp/temp.text','w') as tempfile:
         for line in inputfile:
             old = line.strip().split()
             if old[0] == sys.argv[2]:
                old[0] = sys.argv[3] 
                line = ' '.join(old) + '\n' 
             tempfile.write(line)

os.rename('/tmp/temp.text',sys.argv[1])
```